# is there a way to get the value of each field in sublist using SS 2.0

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

my current issue is, I can't get the value of the field from a sublist in vendor form located at "address tab". here's below used code. Can somebody help me to have a tip for this? Thanks a lot. Uploaded image below that I want to get the value.
[image]

```
var label = vendor_record.getCurrentSublistValue({sublistId:'addressbook',fieldId:'country'};
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you're missing a closing `)` in your row above, before the closing `;`

Anyways, try this instead:

```
            var vendor_record = record.load({
                type: record.Type.VENDOR,
                id: 177270,
                isDynamic: true
            });

            var addressSubrecord = vendor_record.getCurrentSublistSubrecord({
                sublistId: 'addressbook',
                fieldId: 'addressbookaddress'
            });

            var cityValue = addressSubrecord.getValue({
                fieldId: 'country'
            });

            var cityText = addressSubrecord.getText({
                fieldId: 'country'
            });
```

Not sure if you want the value or text of the Country field but simply choose between `getValue()` or `getText()`, but I printed both in the code above just so you can see. In the case above, `cityValue` would output "SE" and `cityText` would output "Sweden".

Comment: yup, you're right but i already tested that with different country name but the still outputted 'PH' or 'Philippines' and also tried to get the values of other fields "no output displayed.

Comment: i also read the document and the codes are same but still not updating the right value needed to be output.

Comment: Do you have more than one address on that record? And want to pick a specific one? In that case, is the problem that you get the wrong country?

Comment: i only have one address, yup want to pick specific one and i have already have condition for that but i want is to get first the value of "country" from the addressbookaddress sublistsubrecord.

Comment: @Bebeto not sure what you mean by the first value of country, is it a list/dropdown? If so, I don't see how you could have more than one value?

Comment: sorry @nyy, yup it's list/dropdown and i mean is still can't get the value of country. it always return PH or Philippines even though the value was different.

i.e: country == SE or Sweden
output: PH or Philippines

Comment: @Bebeto sorry not sure what it could be... sounds super strange, but so hard to know without seeing the environment myself.